# RxJS: How to have one Observer process multiple Observables?

Tags: javascript, reactive-programming, rxjs

I am working with a framework that calls a function I implement. I would like the parameter of this function to be converted to an Observable, and sent through a sequence of Observers. I thought I could use a Subject for this, but it isn't behaving as I expected.

To clarify, I have something like the following code. I thought `Option 1` below would work, but so far I am settling for `Option 2`, which doesn't seem idiomatic at all.

```
var eventSubject = new Rx.Subject();
var resultSource = eventSubject.map(processEvent);
var subscription = resultSource.subscribe(
    function(event) {
        console.log("got event", event);
    },
    function(e) {
        log.error(e);
    },
    function() {
        console.log('eventSubject onCompleted');
    }
);

// The framework calls this method
function onEvent(eventArray) {

   var eventSource = Rx.Observable.from(eventArray);

   // Option 1: I thought this would work, but it doesn't
   // eventSource.subscribe(eventSubject);

   // Option 2: This does work, but its obviously clunky
  eventSource.subscribe(
      function(event) {
          log.debug("sending to subject");
          eventSubject.onNext(event);
      },
      function(e) {
          log.error(e);
      },
      function() {
          console.log('eventSource onCompleted');
      }
  );
}
```

Comment: is that `onEvent` handler something you register yourself?

Comment: In any case, what I can think about uses `Subject.create(observer, observable)` and does not really result in something less clunky as the observer you will pass will do exactly the same than the one you passed to the `eventSource.subscribe`, so let's see other people's propositions.

Comment: @user3743222 - onEvent is a function I write, my framework (loopback) knows the function exists and calls it from its own code. I can't use the fromEvent() or fromEventPattern() methods since they don't match up to the framework's method of registering handlers.

Comment: ok, my idea was to write your own `fromLoopbackEvent`, but that will not likely result in less code. You can have a look at the implementation of `Rx.DOM.fromWebSocket` for an example of using the `Subject.create(observer, observable)` form. Or the documentation : https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md#rxsubjectcreateobserver-observable. The point is you need to specify the observer, there is probably no default observer. So doing it your way, or the other way is about the same I think but let's see.

Comment: The `Rx.Observable.prototype.subscribe` expects an observer or three functions, and a subject is not an observer. So alternatively you might try to convert the subject to a proper observer with `eventSource.subscribe(eventSubject.asObserver())`. Cf.https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/observer.md. The default behaviour is an `onNext` method which sends to the observable linked to the subject.

Comment: @user3743222 a Subject *is* an observer.  It is also an observable.

Comment: True that. I got confused with the anonymous observer` in the source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is just that when you subscribe the whole `Subject` to an observable, you end up subscribing the `onComplete` event of that observable to the subject.  Which means when the observable completes, it will complete your subject.  So when you get the next set of events, they do nothing because the subject is already complete.

One solution is exactly what you did.  Just subscribe the `onNext` event to the subject.

A second solution, and arguably more "rx like" is to treat your incoming data as an observable of observables and flatten this observable stream with [mergeAll](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/mergeall.md):

```
var eventSubject = new Rx.Subject(); // observes observable sequences
var resultSource = eventSubject
  .mergeAll() // subscribe to each inner observable as it arrives
  .map(processEvent);
var subscription = resultSource.subscribe(
    function(event) {
        console.log("got event", event);
    },
    function(e) {
        log.error(e);
    },
    function() {
        console.log('eventSubject onCompleted');
    }
);

// The framework calls this method
function onEvent(eventArray) {

   var eventSource = Rx.Observable.from(eventArray);
   // send a new inner observable sequence
   // into the subject
   eventSubject.onNext(eventSource);
}
```

Update: [Here is a running example](http://jsbin.com/doselejeka/edit?js,console)

Comment: Silly question: Is it possible to make the onNext, onError, onComplete combo into an object (possibly an Observer)? So that the whole thing can be moved to another file for modularity? I'd like to do something like `resultSource.subscribe(mySink)` (which is more fluid), right now I have to do `mySink(resultSource)`, where mySink does the subscription internally

Comment: This usage of `.merge()` doesn't seem to match the documentation: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/merge.md

Comment: Do you mean `.mergeAll()`? See docs: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/mergeall.md

Comment: Yes I guess the merge I linked to doesn't support not supplying a maxConcurrent parameter.

Comment: Sorry, I can't get this to work. I'll try and whip up a jsbin soon

Comment: this answer has helped mi a lot with my issue which seemed to have additional level of complexity. Note that to process promises instead of events the key is order of processing each single element. Thus for more complex cases it should be considered to limit concurrency with `mergeAll(1)` and wrapping async logic (i.e. promises instead of events) with `Observable.defer()`. Full story here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38815109/order-of-execution-for-rxjs-observable-from-chained-promises

Answer (score 3):

As Brandon already explained, subscribing the eventSubject to another observable means subscribing the eventSubjects onNext, onError and onComplete to that observables onNext, onError and onComplete. From your example you seem to only want to subscribe to onNext.

Your subject completes/errros once the first eventSource completes/errors - your eventSubject correctly ignores any further onNext/onError fired on it by subsequent eventSoures.

There are multiple ways to only subscribe to the onNext of any eventSource:

1. Manually subscribe to only onNext.

   ```
   resultSource = eventSubject
     .map(processEvent);

   eventSource.subscribe(
       function(event) {
           eventSubject.onNext(event);
       },
       function(error) {
           // don't subscribe to onError
       },
       function() {
           // don't subscribe to onComplete
       }
   );
   ```
2. Use an operator that handles only subscribing to the eventSources onNext/onError for you. This is what Brandon suggested. **Keep in mind this also subscribes to the eventSources onError, which you don't seem to want as of your example.**

   ```
   resultSource = eventSubject
     .mergeAll()
     .map(processEvent);

   eventSubject.onNext(eventSource);
   ```
3. Use an observer that doesn't call the eventSubjects onError/onComplete for the eventSources onError/onComplete. You could simply overwrite the eventSubjects onComplete as a dirty hack, but it's probably better to create a new observer.

   ```
   resultSource = eventSubject
     .map(processEvent);

   var eventObserver = Rx.Observer.create(
     function (event) {
       eventSubject.onNext(event);
     }
   );

   eventSubject.subscribe(eventObserver);
   ```